# new image size problem

Tags: jquery

how to set an image width and height in lightbox using jquery when first we use the zoom in or out then its works but when click on previous and next then all div's size ok but new image size is not getting actual image size.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you provide some more detail and/or code? What do you mean by "zoom", the browser's zoom function?`

Comment: Hi. It's very hard to understand what you're asking for. Can you please try to improve your question with more details? We also like to see actual code, otherwise it's hard to answer with any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question tags, i assume you are using jquery. You need to use the load() function when you load your image, so the image is fully loaded before other things are done it to. Otherwise you will lose the image dimensions if other things are executed before image is fully loaded.Check the jquery load() function at http://api.jquery.com/load-event/